# Is it possible to add select columns based on the field value?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, database, datatable

I have a report in my web app to display the first 4 changes in `value` field in table. So basically, it will display the first 4 values in `value` column.

Currently, I created sql script and this will display the log level, auditable_id, value.

Current Query Result:

| log_level | auditable_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 |
| 4 | 2 | 6 |

This should be the output:

| auditable_id | log_level_1 | log_level_2 | log_level_3 | log_level_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

Please see the attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```
select 
  auditable_id,
  max(case when log_level =1 then value end )  as log_level_1,
  max(case when log_level =2 then value end )  as log_level_2,
  max(case when log_level =3 then value end )  as log_level_3,
  max(case when log_level =4 then value end )  as log_level_4
  from tbl group by auditable_id;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/undXRRAW)